# Best practices for testing Controllers in Spring Boot: Should I assert actual values in the response body or just its presence?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

In my Spring Boot application, I have a layered architecture with Controllers, Services, and Repositories, each with their corresponding DTOs/Models. I am writing unit tests for my Controllers and am unsure about the extent to which I should assert the response body.

Here's a simplified scenario to illustrate my question:

Suppose I have a BookController with a GET /books/{id} endpoint that fetches a book's details. The response body contains a BookDTO with fields like id, title, author, etc.

```
@GetMapping("/books/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<BookDTO> getBook(@PathVariable Long id) {
    BookDTO bookDTO = bookService.getBook(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(bookDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When unit testing this GET endpoint, I am currently verifying the HTTP status and asserting the actual values in the BookDTO response body, like this:

```
@Test
void getBookTest() throws Exception {
    // mock service method
    when(bookService.getBook(anyLong())).thenReturn(new BookDTO(1L, "Title", "Author"));

    // perform request and verify status
    mockMvc.perform(get("/books/1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(1L))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.title").value("Title"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.author").value("Author"));
}
```

While this test is thorough, it's also tightly coupled to the structure of BookDTO. If BookDTO changes (e.g., a field is added, removed, or renamed), I'll need to update all tests that assert its values, which seems not very maintainable.

I am considering a different approach where I only assert the presence of the response body, not its exact contents. I would then write separate unit tests for BookDTO to ensure it behaves correctly.

My question is: In terms of best practices for unit testing Controllers in Spring Boot, should I assert the actual values in the response body, or just the presence of the body? I understand that it may depend on the specific context, but I'd appreciate any general guidelines or considerations. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think by asserting the response body, you are ensuring that the controller is producing a non-empty response. But simply checking for the presence of a response body doesn't confirm that the correct data is being returned.

By also asserting the actual values in the response body, you can verify that the controller is returning the expected data in the correct format.

One more important consideration when writing unit tests for controllers is to ensure that you are testing the behavior of the controller in isolation from other components of your application. For example, if your controller relies on a database or external API, you may want to use mock objects to simulate those dependencies during testing.

So I Think asserting both the presence and the actual values in the response body is generally useful to follow for unit testing controllers in Spring Boot.

I also found some useful notes [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)

Comment: To ensure the correctness of the body, there are junit tests written for the model classes. 

If the object is not properly created, my controller test will pass ofcourse, but the flow for creating the model will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think that those tests are at service level, so these are blackbox tests. The meaning of this kind of tests is to validate the right response to a concrete input. I think that you are doing it right verifying the content of the response.

So, how we can reduce the effort to maintain that?
There are multiple ways, it depends on how the tests are structured, but in this case i think that the problem is that you have to repeat a lot of time this code in the same class:

```
    @Test
void getBookTest() throws Exception {
    // mock service method
    when(bookService.getBook(anyLong())).thenReturn(new BookDTO(1L, "Title", "Author"));

    // perform request and verify status
    mockMvc.perform(get("/books/1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(1L))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.title").value("Title"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.author").value("Author"));
}
```

So you can covert it into this:

```
    // No test annotation it's a private method in the class
private void getBookTest(BookDTO bookDto, String bookRequest) throws Exception { 
    // mock service method
    when(bookService.getBook(anyLong())).thenReturn(bookDto);

    // perform request and verify status
    mockMvc.perform(get(bookRequest))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(bookDto.getId()))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.title").value(bookDto.getTitle()))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.author").value(bookDto.getAuthor()));
}
```

And then you only have to update one mehtod when you change the JSON. And call it from each test as following:

```
getBookTest(new BookDTO(1L, "Title", "Author"), "/books/1")
```

Even if you are using always the same BookDTO instance you can do it better, creating that instance at class level field and call it like this:

```
private BookDTO bookDTO = new BookDTO(1L, "Title", "Author") //you better create the instance in a constructor

.......
getBookTest(bookDto, "/books/1")
```